# Append following code on previous line in ssis

Tags: ssis

Is there a way to append info from 1 column to another column on the previous line using SSIS and remove any HTML tags in the process?

I have various data files that came in and need to be cleaned up. They would like to move away from using Macros and start using SSIS packages to do all the work. I have attached an image of an example, and what I would need to have done is to start at the last row and work my way up. If column A is a number then skip to the next, but if it is not and column G is empty take column A and append it to the offset -1 column G and remove any HTML tags in the process. This would be done on a much bigger scale too. I have it working in VBA as seen below, but like I said it needs to be done in SSIS, and I dont know how. [image], [image]
[image]

Comment: You would basically be trading your Excel VBScript macros for a Script Task/Component (with either C# or Visual Basic .NET) as the language.  Does the data actually start in Excel or are you opening a file extract (CSV, TXT, TSV, etc) in Excel and because column H has a carriage return/line feed in it, Excel interprets it poorly?

Comment: A data flow component itself will not have the concept of previous row so that's why you'll be writing scripts to do all this heavy lifting

Comment: This would start in a csv file. Do you know where I can find examples of this to help me along. I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction as I am not fluent in C# or SSIS.

Comment: Open the original CSV with something like notepad. Copy the first N rows and edit that into your question so we can see how the data is laid out

Comment: I added a screen shot of the layout

Comment: While a screenshot is helpful to convey a sense of the data file, how can we reproduce your problem, much less provide a solution if we don't have actual data to work with?

Comment: Do you have any influence over the generation of this file? It's like someone is parsing parts of a webpage to make a csv and doing so poorly. Also, how do we get from the CSV screenshot to the Excel data? Looks like the data in the screenshot is just CSS formatting

Comment: It is sensitive data and can not place it out there for all to see. They tried to rename all data with the word placeholder. They are migrating from DB2 to SQL Server. This is how the data came in. I am told to clean it up. I realize the HTML looks terrible. I need to start from the bottom and if Column A data is not a number kick over the data from column A to column H and if it is a number leave that row alone and move to the next one up.

Comment: Column A seems to be catching data after a CR|LF. So I need to make whatever was in the webpage as a lined statement as a 1 line data entry. So I need to remove any HTML tags and then bring the text together as one line.

Comment: Pseudologic  is going to be "Skip first 4 lines" Read Line - if row length is (whatever length is for the row that begins with 540746 and ends with a comma), then peek at the next line. If next line starts with digits, then current row was complete. If next line ends with 7? commas, then it was a continuation. Accumulate continued lines until you find line starting with digits.